# How to Rename multiple files name by power-shell or hyper.js in Windows 10 with one commend

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file

I have files such as:

[image]

How can I replace `example` to `test-file` in each of them?

I want solutions for:

1. Batch file
2. PowerShell
3. Bash

Comment: You have been member for long enough to know that it is beyond the scope of SO to teach you how to code something in CMD, Powershell, bash or whatever. Choose one of the languages start to code and when you run into problems you're welcome to come back and get help.

Comment: I can change file or rename all of those by CMD, But I need to how run a loop for change example word to new file name. I am sure you know my answer but You ignore me !!!

Comment: If I'm allowed to recommend something for you: Start learning the very basics of Powershell. You will probably learn what you need for this task in the very first lessons. It does not take long but I'm sure it will pay off for you in the future.

Comment: @Olaf  Can you help me by refer a book for learn Powershell. I am interested.

Comment: @MDAshik, please refresh your understanding of how this site works. You should be aware that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please consider, refreshing your knowledge by retaking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D "example*"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    rename "%%~fA" "!fname:example=test-file!%%~xA"
)
```

which should work. If you don't want to hardcode the word to replace, use:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "word=test-file"

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D "example*"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    rename "%%~fA" "!fname:example=%word%!%%~xA"
)
```

For [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) one-line use:

```bat
for /F "delims=" %A IN ('dir /b /a-d "example*"') do @set "fname=%~nA"&call rename "%~fA" "%fname:example=test-file%%~xA"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution:

   ```bat
   @For %%A In (example*)Do @Set "_=%%A"&Call Ren "%%A" "test-file%%_:*example=%%"
   ```
2. As one has not yet been submitted, here's a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) answer:

   ```bat
   Get-ChildItem -Filter 'example*' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '^example','test-file'}
   ```

   You could of course utilise `PowerShell` from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

   ```bat
   @Powershell -NoP "GCI -Filt 'example*'|RnI -N {$_.Name -Replace '^example','test-file'}"
   ```
3. For a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution, you're going to need to be more specific, because different OS'es/distributions etc. use different methods, some may use `rename` from util-Linux others may use the Perl `rename` utility. Others may not have `rename` and need to utilise a `for` loop with the `mv` command.

   ```bat
   for f in example*; do mv "$f" "${f/example/test-file}"
   ```

---

**[Edit /]**

To run a command from the Command Prompt despite your lack of a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag:

```bat
For %A In (example*)Do @Set "_=%A"&Call Ren "%A" "test-file%_:*example=%"
```

Comment: `powershell` commend working nice but `batch` *commend* make error for double %%, it will be single % 

it will be single and it make file name like *%test-file%*

Comment: @MDAshik, there is nothing wrong with my batch file example. The issue is that you've decided to treat my batch file as a command line and attempted to run it as is in the command prompt. In fact my batch file example, unlike the one you've accepted as your answer, replaces only the first instance of `example`. Let's say the file was named `example.example.ts`, mine would rename it to `test-file.example.ts`, the answer you've accepted would rename it to `test-file.test-file.ts`. As you appear to want a command prompt, `cmd.exe` example, I've now included one in my answer; _Please retry it!_

Comment: @MDAshik, I would also like to add that not only have you not ran my command properly and accepted an 'inferior' solution, your question asked for three solutions and mine is the only answer to have obliged, _despite your question being off topic_. I ask that you please review my answers, test all three, _or now four_, solutions and provide feedback appropriate for the time and effort I have afforded to your request; thank you.

Comment: – Compo Thanks for your afforded :( But last time I was trying by my way, but I was fail. I don't know why :( I already gave you upvote .

Comment: @MDAshik, I've told you why! All of my answers work exactly as I have posted them. **You did not run my batch file answer as a batch file and because of that you incorrectly decided that the error was mine and chose somebody else's answer**. I'm going to say this again, **the answer you have chosen does not provide a PowerShell or 'bash' answer, it only satisfies the batch file request. Additionally the answer you've accepted is inferior to mine, as it replaces all instances of `example`, not just leading instances**. Please run my commands, and prove to me that they do not work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can use `rename` command like this:

```
 rename example test-file example*
```

Here first argument is `required` expression to be changed, second argument is `replacement` and last argument is `file name`

Comment: But i want to rename all of files by one commend .